# php empty() or isset() checking more than 1 variable

Tags: php

I use

```
if(!empty($_POST['login'])){
}
```

for checking that login is file is filled, it work when I checking 1 variable, but not working when I use

```
if(!empty($_POST['login'],$_POST['password'] )){
}
```

how to check 2 variables, I see that isset() too support only 1 variable

Comment: isset will take multiple variables - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: you mean `var_dump(isset($a, $b)); // TRUE` ?

Comment: `isset($a, $b)` will return true if $a and $b are both set; is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a logical and operation (`&&`) along with two calls to `empty()`, like so:

```
if( !empty( $_POST['login']) && !empty( $_POST['password'])) {
    // $_POST['login'] and $_POST['password'] are both not empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
function isempty(){ // Function checks if all of the given arguments are empty
    $empty = true;
    $numargs = func_num_args(); // get the number of given Arguments
    $arg_list = func_get_args(); // get the given Arguments

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $empty = $empty && empty($arg_list[$i]);                      
    }
    return $empty;
}
```

You can call it like this: `!isempty($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'])`

I have not tested the code, but it should be fine